# Is it possible to extract a cell value from a tabular array?

Tags: tables, extract, cell

In a documentation application, where the version history of the document is listed in a tabular environment, I'd like to be able to silently extract the value of the last version number supplied, to use elsewhere. The people who type in the metadata can't (and shouldn't be able to) add markup to what they enter, so I thought of something like this:

Minimal NON-working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\def\foo{0}
\begin{tabular}{>{\gdef\foo\bgroup}c<{\egroup}cc}
Ver&Stuff&More stuff\\\hline
0.1&this&that\\
0.2&this&that\\
0.3&this&that\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to end up with \foo as '0.3'.  This is probably the wrong way to go about it, but has anyone a solution?

Answer (score 6):

You're not far: `collcell` provides the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\deffoo}[1]{\gdef\foo{#1}#1}
\def\foo{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\deffoo}c<{\endcollectcell}cc}
Ver&Stuff&More stuff\\\hline
0.1&this&that\\
0.2&this&that\\
0.3&this&that\\
\end{tabular}

\foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your approach cannot work, because the replacement text for a `\def` (or friends) cannot be delimited by `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, only by explicit braces. Instead, we inject `\collectcell\deffoo` at the start of the cell and `\endcollectcell` at the end. Essentially, `\collectcell` is defined by

```
\def\collectcell#1#2\endcollectcell{#1{#2}}
```

so what's executed is `\deffoo{<cell contents>}`, which does what we need.

Comment: Oooh! Thanks, I hadn't come across this one before: I was searching for 'capture' rather than 'collect'.